# Vlookup will not loop to next column

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, vlookup

I am trying to get the vlookup to loop down to the last row and 5 columns.

The vlookup goes to the last row, but won't loop to the next column, instead it continues to the next row.

I have tried changing the row, updated spaces and rewritten the next to ensure correct spacing.

The goal is to have the vlookup to continue to last row, then move to next column 5 times.

```
Sub Trial()

    'vlookup to get extra data over
    Workbooks("Final SOR.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").Activate

    Dim LastRowLP As Long

    LastRowLP = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim for_col As Long, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, colnum As Long

    r = 2: c = 4: colnum = 2

    For for_col = 1 To 5    
        For i = 1 To LastRowLP
            Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(r, c).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 1).Value, Sheets("UsedData").Range("A:F"), colnum, 0)
            r = r + 1
        Next
        r = 2
        colnum = colnum + 1
        c = c + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: One thing I've noticed, you are looping on `i` here `For i = 1 To LastRowLP`, but you are not using `i` at all, you are using `r` for your rows reference, and later you increment `r` with `r = r + 1`

Comment: Also, you are looping `For for_col = 1 To 5` but not using `for_col` anywhere else inside your `For` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *r* to stop at *LastRowLP* then use it in the loop or exit the loop when *r* equals *LastRowLP*.

```
Sub Trial()

    'vlookup to get extra data over
    Workbooks("Final SOR.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").Activate

    Dim LastRowLP As Long

    LastRowLP = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim for_col As Long, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, colnum As Long

    r = 2: c = 4: colnum = 2

    For for_col = 1 To 5
        For i = 1 To LastRowLP
            Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(r, c).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 1).Value, Sheets("UsedData").Range("A:F"), colnum, 0)
            r = r + 1
            If r > LastRowLP Then Exit For    'exit the loop
        Next
        r = 2
        colnum = colnum + 1
        c = c + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

A little math and you can simplify matters by using *r* and *c* as the increments in the loop.

```
Sub Trial2()

    'vlookup to get extra data over

    Dim VLUR As Range
    Dim LastRowLP As Long

    With Workbooks("Final SOR.xlsm")

        Set VLUR = .Sheets("UsedData").Range("A:F")

        With Sheets("Sheet3")

            LastRowLP = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            Dim r As Long, c As Long

            For c = 4 To 8
                For r = 2 To LastRowLP
                    .Cells(r, c).Value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(r, 1).Value, VLUR, c - 2, 0)
                Next r
            Next c

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```